# Slide Toggle [Jquery Function] Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I use this code to run a slide toggle but it doesn't open when I click on it:

JS Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         alert('hi i came to toggle');
         $(".flip").click(function () {
             $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
         });
     });

      function ViewGetSubjects(data) {
         var subjects = (typeof data) == 'string' ? eval('(' + data + ')') : data;
         $('#subjects').empty();
         for (var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++)
          {
              $('#subjects').append('<h1 class = "flip">'+subjects[i].Wkp_lesson+'</h1><div class="panel" >' + ' Weekly Body: ' + subjects[i].Wkp_Body + ' Weekly Body: ' + subjects[i].Wkp_Body + ' Weekly Lesson: ' + subjects[i].Wkp_lesson + '</div>');
             }
      }
```

CSS:

```
       div.panel,h1.flip
      {
         margin:0px;
         padding:5px;
         text-align:center;
         background:#488AC7;
         border:solid 1px #F6358A;
       }
     div.panel
     {
         height:120px;
         display:none;
     }
```

Do you know why?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What doesn't work here? I created a fiddle for you (http://jsfiddle.net/fvv2n/). Adjust the code to reflect your own, especially the HTML. As it is, it works.

Comment: post your html, and create a sample jsfiddle as @Armatus suggested

Comment: There is no HTML :) It's just: <div id="subjects"></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using latest version of jquery

```
 $(".flip").live('click', function(e){
     $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
 });
```

otherwise it should be

```
$("#subjects").on('click', 'h1.flip', function(e){
    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

because you are appending `DOM`(`h1` with class name `flip`) elements dynamically inside the `#subjects` (element that has id=subjects) element.

References : [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [live (deprecated)](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from my comment, did you possibly forget to include the jquery library?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

This will include the latest version directly from jquery.com, although it is suggested that you copy the code and save it in your own file.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in the answer above? That's more likely to be the problem.